# What to do? Everytime I insert my Apollo M100 USB external drive, Windows 8 telling me to restart to fix driver issues

Tags: windows-8, external-hard-drive

Then after I restarted, its working fine, but when pulled out the drive again and insert it back, the same notification.

I cannot find drivers for it on Imation website, anybody can give me the correct drivers and how to install them.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall all of the drivers, restart the computer, and install them again.
Otherwise try the drive in another computer.